# Как посчитать количество пар в массиве python?

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, list

Как правильнее всего сделать подсчёт количества пар в массиве, например

`d = [1,2,3,2,3,3]`

Тут имеется три пары и одно уникальное число, какой алгоритм перебора и подсчета будет правильнее всего?

Comment: 2 и 2 пара...и патом 3 пары троек чтоли ?

Comment: Какие пары вы считатете? Пары равных? Пары различных? Пары соседних? Упорядоченные пары? Неупорядоченные пары?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще надо проверять только "нижний треугольник" квадрата, но это надо индексы сравнивать, проще посчитать все пары, потом вычесть совпадения чисел самих с собой и поделить на 2, чтобы убрать повторные совпадения с другой стороны диагонали:

```
lst = [1,2,3,2,3,3]
print((sum(a == b for a in lst for b in lst) - len(lst))//2)
# 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

d = [1,2,3,2,3,3]
counter = Counter(d)
res = sum(v * (v - 1) // 2 for v in counter.values())
print(res) # 4
```

Или

```
d = [1,2,3,2,3,3]
d.sort()
res = 0
s = 1
for i in range(1, len(d)):
    if d[i] == d[i - 1]:
        s += 1
    else:
        res += s * (s - 1) // 2
        s = 1
res += s * (s - 1) // 2
print(res) # 4
```

Оба алгоритма подсчитывают, сколько раз в массиве встречается каждое уникальное число: в данном случае - `{3: 3, 2: 2, 1: 1}`. После чего количество пар считается как количество сочетаний по два из n для каждого уникального числа. То есть количество пар троек в данном случае равно `3 * 2 / 2 = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм далеко не оптимален, но на небольших массивах будет работать чудесно.

```
def count_pairs(l):
    pairs = []
    for i, el in enumerate(l):
        for i2, el2 in enumerate(l):
            if el == el2 and i != i2:
                if (i, i2) not in pairs and (i2, i) not in pairs:
                    pairs += [(i, i2)]
    return len(pairs)

print(count_pairs([1,2,3,2,3,3]))
```

Comment: Можно проверять `i < i2` и тогда проверка на вхождение перевёрнутой пары индексов в список лишняя.